# UCanAccess ConstraintViolationException not being caught

Tags: ucanaccess

I have created a composite index in a Microsoft Access Database on three fields. The index works if I try to manually add rows which violates the index. It also works in the Javafx program as it causes this exception:
UCAExc:::4.0.2 integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation; CLASS_CHECKROOM table: CLASS

I am trying to catch this exception without the app crashing but to no avail.
I have tried:

```
}catch (SQLException ex) {
        if(ex.getMessage().contains("integrity")) {

            Alert alertUpdateOK = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alertUpdateOK.setTitle("Double Booked");
            alertUpdateOK.setContentText(ex.getMessage());
            alertUpdateOK.show();
       } 
   }
```

This outputs "No error" and then the exception occurs
and:

```
   }catch (SQLException ex) {
        
            Alert alertUpdateOK = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alertUpdateOK.setTitle("Double Booked");
            alertUpdateOK.setContentText(ex.getMessage());
            alertUpdateOK.show();
       } 
   }
```

This just causes the exception with no alert and the app crashes

I have seen some solutions involving error code for the exception
and as I understand Ucanaccess uses HSQLDB I have tried error codes 25 58 and 104

```
}catch (SQLException ex) {
            if (ex.getSQLState().startsWith("25")) {        
                    
            Alert alertUpdateOK = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alertUpdateOK.setTitle("Double Booked");
            alertUpdateOK.setContentText(ex.getMessage());
            alertUpdateOK.show();
            }
        }
```

"No error"
PID repeated. Enter a different PID

Help would be appreciated. The whole code is

```
public void insertIntoDB() throws SQLException{
        Connection connection =null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        
        
        if (Integer.parseInt(start) < Integer.parseInt(finish)) {
        try {
            connection =AccessConnect.Connector();
            String sql = "INSERT INTO Class(ClassName, WeekDay, ClassStart, ClassFinish, TeacherID, classAge, MaxSize, RoomID, subjectID) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            
            
            preparedStatement.setString(1, classname);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, weekday);
            preparedStatement.setString(3, start);
            preparedStatement.setString(4,finish);
            preparedStatement.setInt(5, teacherid);
            preparedStatement.setInt(6, classage);
            preparedStatement.setInt(7, maxsize);
            preparedStatement.setInt(8, roomid);
            preparedStatement.setInt(9,subjectid);
            
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            
        }catch (SQLException ex) {
            
            Alert alertUpdateOK = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alertUpdateOK.setTitle("Double Booked");
            alertUpdateOK.setContentText(ex.getMessage());
            alertUpdateOK.show();
       } 
   
        
        finally {
            if (preparedStatement != null)
                preparedStatement.close();
            if (connection !=null)
                
                connection.close();
        }
}
        
        else {
            Alert alertUpdateOK = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alertUpdateOK.setTitle("Times are wrong");
            alertUpdateOK.setContentText(" The start time has to be before the end time");
            alertUpdateOK.show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to capture the exception in an alert box. I was using eclipse and I needed to
Clean the project and it worked